# How to group data with color but still show a trendline for the entire dataset using Plotly Express?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

I'm getting a trend line, however the issue is that with color and a trendline (set to max of data points), I'm getting multiple lines. I only want one line on the entire data set. Here is my code:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, "Date", y="Number", color="Technology", labels={
                     "Date": "Year",
                     "Number": "Number"
                 }, trendline="expanding", trendline_options=dict(function="max"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're assigning different colors to different categories for a plotly express figure like you've done here with `color="Technology`, you can add the following to set the [scope of the trendline](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/) to cover all data points and ignore the subcategories indicatd by color:

```
trendline_scope="overall"
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

import plotly.express as px

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", symbol="smoker", color="sex", trendline="ols", trendline_scope="overall")
fig.show()
```